# How to create the function of an arrow being shot?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

Suppose we have an arrow that is being shot and we know the angle, starting $\upsilon_{0x}$ velocity and starting $\upsilon_{0y}$ velocity. Assuming the arrow lands on the same level as it is being shot, $\left(x_f,y_f\right)=\left(0,0\right)=\left(x_i,y_i\right)$, is it possible to create the function $y=f(x)$ that has input $x$ and outputs the $y$ position of the arrow? Arrow aerodynamics and air resistance are negligible. If not, which other bits of information are needed?

I have tried creating specific parabolas with the form $f(x)=(x-m)(x-n)$ or  with the form $f(x)=a(x-p)^2+q$, and tried something with the kinematics formulas, but as inexperienced as I am about this topic, it was to no avail. I don't even know whether a parabola is possible for each bow shot.
Thanks in advance.

*This is for a simulation I'm making where I'll later calculate the tangent slope of the formula, so I can give the arrow some curvature in the air.*

Comment: How about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Displacement)? In general, something under a search for "projectile motion" is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

$$x=u_{x}t$$

$$y= u_{y}t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$$

Rearranging:

$$\frac{x}{u_{x}} = t$$

Substituting into y:

$$y= u_{y}\left(\frac{x}{u_{x}}\right) + \frac{1}{2}a\left(\frac{x}{u_{x}}\right)^2$$

If we want to define your velocity in terms of an angle

Let:

$$u_{x} = u\cos(\theta)$$
$$u_{y} = u \sin(\theta)$$

$$y= tan(\theta) x + \frac{1}{2}a\frac{x^2 \sec^2(\theta)}{u^2}$$